# How to use the functions of a variable by using a same string name rather than the variable name?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm struggle in a reflection problem, actually I'm not sure whether it is a reflection problem, but the situation is shown below.

```
public Image IMG1;
int x = 1;
string temp;
temp = "IMG" + x.ToString(); //Now temp is a string with value "IMG1"
```

In Image class, we have "sprite" propety that we can call. Is it possible to use something like "temp.sprite" rather than "IMG1.sprite"?

```
public Sprite newSprite;
IMG1.sprite = newSprite;
```

change to

```
temp.sprite = newSprite;
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: instead of using a string (for temp), you would have to create a `MyClass` (for temp) which contains a `Sprite` property. You can then override `MyClass.ToString()` to compose the string as you want it to be composed. However, this is a relatively cumbersome approach; which may be completely overengineered for your case. If you provide some context as to what you're hoping to achieve overall; we can give you a more accurate answer that avoids overkill.

Comment: `temp` is string and does not have the `sprite` property so **No**. I think you should explain why and what exactly you are doing. This will help so many people answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if You need to use reflection in your case.
But I would suggest to try go with Dictionary. So at the begining You need to add all of yours Image fields to dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Image> dict = new Dictionary<string, Image>();
dict.Add(nameof(IMG1), IMG1);
```

Then You can access your field by:

```
dict[temp].sprite = xxxx
```

This approach is much better when it comes to performance.
But if You really need do it by reflection, You can look into 'dynamic' keyword which simplify use of reflection if You are not familiar with it.

Or by using regular reflection You can try something like this:

```
FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(YourClassWithImageField).GetField(temp);
Image img = fieldInfo.GetValue(ObjectWithYourField) as Image;
if (img != null)
{
    img.sprite = xxxx;
}
```

Hope it helps.